# Spark - Unable to calculate parquet min/max statistics for string columns

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I have enabled "spark.parquet.strings.signed-min-max.enabled" property for a spark job. While inspecting min/max parquet statistics, still statistics is not calculated or displayed for the string columns for the parquet data.

I see the following for string columns.
VLE:PLAIN DICTIONARY ST:[no stats for this column]

I used the following command to inspect statistics:

```
hadoop jar parquet-tools-1.9.0.jar dump -d -n
```

Would it be possible to enable statistics for string columns? If so, should any configurations or encoding be changed?
Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.